# Multiple Javascript Framework on a single application

Tags: javascript, laravel, frameworks

I have a project handling in which already built most of its features and uses laravel and knockout js. But I want to use Vuejs on this one because I dont know yet about knockout and I like vuejs. My concern is, is it possible that I can use both witout conflicting, or im thinking to use vue for specific part of the applicaiton like, live web alerts.

please let me know the pros and cons about this, thank you.

Comment: You can use it .Check [this](https://github.com/CanopyTax/single-spa)., but also think what is the use case of it. Is it really worthy? Will it be maintainable? Can a single resource maintain all the frameworks? Is it going to make your life easy?  Is it really going to be useful or you just want to explore it for sake of learning.

Comment: brk, thank you. I actually research about it. at first I thought this was just learning but if I compare the two framework , vue will win right? but I think I will give it a try atleast for one module at it is possible and not do harm on current project state.